# Python summing selected values in a column that match given condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, sum

Here's the data after the preliminary data cleaning.

| year | country | employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | US | 9 |
| 2001 | Canada | 81 |
| 2001 | France | 22 |
| 2001 | Japan | 31 |
| 2001 | Chile | 7 |
| 2001 | Mexico | 15 |
| 2001 | Total | 165 |
| 2002 | US | 5 |
| 2002 | Canada | 80 |
| 2002 | France | 20 |
| 2002 | Japan | 30 |
| 2002 | Egypt | 35 |
| 2002 | Total | 170 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2010 | US | 32 |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I want to get is the table below, which is summing up all countries except "US, Canada, France, and Japan" into 'others'. The list of countries varies every year from 2001 to 2010 so I want to use a for loop with if condition to loop over every year.

| year | country | employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | US | 9 |
| 2001 | Canada | 81 |
| 2001 | France | 22 |
| 2001 | Japan | 31 |
| 2001 | Others | 22 |
| 2001 | Total | 165 |
| 2002 | US | 5 |
| 2002 | Canada | 80 |
| 2002 | France | 20 |
| 2002 | Japan | 30 |
| 2002 | Others | 35 |
| 2002 | Total | 170 |

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you are looking for is in this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964178/add-sum-to-all-grouped-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You may consider dropping `Total` from your dataframe.

However, as stated, your question can be solved by using `Series.where` to map away values that you don't recognize:

```py
country = df["country"].where(df["country"].isin(["US", "Canada", "France", "Japan", "Total"]), "Others")
df.groupby([df["year"], country]).sum(numeric_only=True)
```